# iOS - prevent duplicate add event to calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, ios8, xcode6

I use this code below to add event ,  my code called many times so i have duplicate event , is there any idea to prevent duplicate

Thank You in advance

```
    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:es];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormats = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormats setDateFormat:@"yyy-MM-dd"];

    NSDate *date1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSDate *date2 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    date1 = nil;
    date2 = nil;
    date1 = [dateFormats dateFromString:event2.from_date];
    date2 = [dateFormats dateFromString:event2.to_date];


    event.title  = event2.event_title;
    event.allDay = NO;
    event.startDate = date1;
    event.endDate = date2;

    [event addAlarm:[EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:60.0f *60.0f *24]];
    //put here if start and end dates are same
    [event setCalendar:[es defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

    [es saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:nil];
```

Comment: Don't call your code multiple times?

Comment: I have to , to add new event i should called it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm basing my answer off this tutorial [Calendar event management tutorial](http://pragmapilot.wordpress.com/2014/05/29/calendar-event-management-tutorial/). So of course if things don't line up correctly, please reference it.

```
EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:es];
NSDate *date1 = [NSDate new];
NSDate *date2 = [NSDate new];
date1 = nil;
date2 = nil;
date1 = [dateFormats dateFromString:event2.from_date];
date2 = [dateFormats dateFromString:event2.to_date];


event.title  = event2.event_title;
event.allDay = NO;
event.startDate = date1;
event.endDate = date2;

NSPredicate *predicate = [es predicateForEventsWithStartDate:event2.from_date endDate:event2.to_date calendars:nil];
NSArray *eventsOnDate = [es eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];

__block BOOL eventExists = NO;

[eventsOnDate enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    EKEvent *eventToCheck = (EKEvent*)obj;

    if([event.title isEqualToString:eventToCheck.title])
    {
        eventExists = YES;
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];

if(! eventExists) {
    [event addAlarm:[EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:60.0f *60.0f *24]];
    //put here if start and end dates are same
    [event setCalendar:[es defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

    [es saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:nil];


    NSError *saveEventError;
    [es saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error: &saveEventError];

    if(saveEventError) {
        //ERROR OCCURED WHILE SAVING

    } else {
        //SUCCESSFULLY SAVED
    }

} else {
    // EVENT ALREADY EXISTS

}
```

Comment: this nice answer but i prefer make identifier my event id , cause name could be duplicate thank you

Comment: I didn't know you made an `event_id`, but yea, definitely a much better route.

Comment: i think its read only property i can't set any thing as identifier

Comment: I got Error here [es enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate:[es predicateForEventsWithStartDate:date1 endDate:date2 calendars:nil] usingBlock:^(EKEvent *event, BOOL *stop) {
            if ([currentID isEqualToString:[event valueForKey:@"eventID"]]) {
                doesExist = true;
                *stop = true;
            }
        }];